# Deep copy of one-to-many domains in Grails 3

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm confused as to how to implement this or if it's really even possible/appropriate. My colleague and I are building a web app for a client using Grails 3. He created the initial domains which I'm guessing where an almost one-to-one copy from the Realm models from the mobile apps. I've since modified them in an attempt to get some form of deep cloning to work as three domains have a one-to-many relationship.

**The Problem**

How would I go about creating a deep copy of a domain? I have tried suggested answers with little success:

- [Proper Implementation of clone() For Domain Classes to duplicate a Grails domain instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20220711/proper-implementation-of-clone-for-domain-classes-to-duplicate-a-grails-domain)
- [can GORM duplicate whole object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26031825/can-gorm-duplicate-whole-object)
- [Cloning an instance of domain in Grails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27217445/cloning-an-instance-of-domain-in-grails)

Picking ideas from various places I've come to formulating a `clone(Domain)` method shown below. It *almost* works (I think), but has issues with the collections throwing a `HibernateException - Found shared references to a collection: Location.equipments`.

Called in a controller as:

```
def copy() {
    Survey.clone(Survey.get(params.id))
    redirect action: 'index'
}
```

Any ideas or guidance?

Currently the domains are the following:

```
class Survey {

    int id
    String name
    String contactName
    String contactEmail
    String facilityAddress
    String facilityCity
    String facilityStateProvince
    String facilityZip
    String distributorName
    String distributorEmail
    String distributorPhoneNumber

    static Survey clone(Survey self) {
        Survey clone = new Survey()
        String exclude = "locations"

        clone.properties = self.properties.findAll {
            it.key != exclude
        }

        self.locations.each {
            Location copy = Location.clone it
            clone.addToLocations copy
        }

        clone.save()
    }

    static transients = ['clone']
    static belongsTo = User
    static hasMany = [locations: Location]
}
```

---

```
class Location {
    int id
    String name
    String[] hazardsPresent
    HazardType[] hazardTypes
    ExposureArea[] exposureArea
    RiskLevel exposureLevel
    String comments
    byte[] picture

    static Location clone(Location self) {
        Location clone = new Location()
        String[] excludes = ['equipment', 'products']

        clone.properties = self.properties.findAll {
            !(it.key in excludes)
        }

        self.equipments.each {
            Equipment copy = Equipment.clone it
            self.addToEquipments copy
        }

        self.products.each {
            RecommendedProduct copy = new RecommendedProduct()
            copy.properties = it.properties
            copy.save()
            clone.addToProducts copy
        }

        clone.save()
    }

    static transients = ['clone']
    static belongsTo = Survey
    static hasMany = [equipments: Equipment, products: RecommendedProduct]
    static constraints = {
        picture(maxSize: 1024 * 1024)
    }
}
```

---

```
class Equipment {
    int id
    EquipmentType type
    String name
    Brand brand

   // Redacted 26 boolean properties
   // ...

    static Equipment clone(Equipment self) {
        Equipment clone = new Equipment()
        String exclude = "extras"

        clone.properties = self.properties.findAll {
            it.key != exclude
        }

        self.extras.each {
            EquipmentQuestionExtra copy = new EquipmentQuestionExtra()
            copy.properties = it.properties
            copy.save()
            clone.addToExtras copy
        }

        clone.save()
    }

    static transients = ['clone']
    static belongsTo = Location
    static hasMany = [extras: EquipmentQuestionExtra]
}
```

---

```
class RecommendedProduct {
    int productId
    int quantityChosen
    String comment

    static belongsTo = Location
}
```

---

```
class EquipmentQuestionExtra {
    int id
    String questionText
    String comment
    byte[] picture

    static belongsTo = Equipment
    static constraints = {
        picture(maxSize: 1024 * 1024)
    }
}
```

Comment: the cloning that you are doing should be cloning every object irrespective of its type. Hence, clone the collections as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been almost a year and I've since completed this project with a solution to this problem.

The solution I came up with was utilizing the [service layer](https://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/services.html). I defined a service for each domain. Any domain that needed to deep copy a collection, called their associated service method. I'm only posting the source of two services as the other methods are essentially the same.

The flow is this:

1. Create a new blank instance of the domain.
2. Copy all 'primitive' properties such as `String`, `Boolean`, etc via `duplicate.properties = original.properties`.
3. Since the above also sets the collection/has-many relationships, this would result in a `HibernateException` about shared collections. So set the collection to `null`.
4. Call the associated service method to copy the collection/has-many.
5. Save and return the duplicated domain.

`service/SurveyService.groovy`

```
class SurveyService {
/**
 * Attempts to perform a deep copy of a given survey
 *
 * @param survey The survey instance to duplicate
 * @return The duplicated survey instance
 */
Survey duplicateSurvey(Survey originalSurvey) {
    Survey duplicatedSurvey = new Survey()

    duplicatedSurvey.properties = originalSurvey.properties
    duplicatedSurvey.locations = null
    duplicatedSurvey.uuid = UUIDGenerator.createUniqueId()
    duplicatedSurvey.dateModified = DateUtil.getCurrentDate()
    duplicatedSurvey.name = "${originalSurvey.name.replace("(copy)", "").trim()} (copy)"
    duplicatedSurvey.save()
    duplicatedSurvey.locations = duplicateLocations originalSurvey.locations, duplicatedSurvey
    duplicatedSurvey.save()
}

/**
 * Attempts to perform a deep copy of a survey's location
 *
 * @param originalLocations The original location set
 * @param duplicatedSurvey The duplicated survey that each survey will belong to
 * @return The duplicated location set
 */
Set<Location> duplicateLocations(Set<Location> originalLocations, Survey duplicatedSurvey) {
    Set<Location> duplicatedLocations = []

    for (originalLocation in originalLocations) {
        duplicatedLocations << locationService.duplicateLocation(originalLocation, duplicatedSurvey)
    }

    duplicatedLocations
}
}
```

`service/LocationService.groovy`

```
class LocationService {
    /**
     * Performs a deep copy of a given location. The duplicated location name is
     * the original location name and the duplicated location ID.
     *
     * @param originalLocation The location to duplicate
     * @param survey The survey that the location will belong to
     * @return The duplicated location
     */
    Location duplicateLocation(Location originalLocation, Survey survey = null) {
        Location duplicatedLocation = new Location()
        duplicatedLocation.properties = originalLocation.properties
        duplicatedLocation.survey = survey ?: duplicatedLocation.survey
        duplicatedLocation.uuid = UUIDGenerator.createUniqueId()
        duplicatedLocation.dateModified = DateUtil.currentDate
        duplicatedLocation.equipments = null
        duplicatedLocation.products = null
        duplicatedLocation.save()
        duplicatedLocation.name = "${originalLocation.name.replace("(copy)", "").trim()} (copy)"
        duplicatedLocation.equipments = duplicateEquipment originalLocation.equipments, duplicatedLocation
        duplicatedLocation.products = duplicateProducts originalLocation, duplicatedLocation
        duplicatedLocation.save()

        duplicatedLocation
    }

    /**
     * Performs a deep copy of a given locations equipments.
     *
     * @param originalEquipments The original locations equipments
     * @param duplicatedLocation The duplicated location; needed for belongsTo association
     * @return The duplicated equipment set.
     */
    Set<Equipment> duplicateEquipment(Set<Equipment> originalEquipments, Location duplicatedLocation) {
        Set<Equipment> duplicatedEquipments = []

        for (originalEquipment in originalEquipments) {
            Equipment duplicatedEquipment = new Equipment()
            duplicatedEquipment.properties = originalEquipment.properties
            duplicatedEquipment.uuid = UUIDGenerator.createUniqueId()
            duplicatedEquipment.dateModified = DateUtil.currentDate
            duplicatedEquipment.location = duplicatedLocation
            duplicatedEquipment.extras = null
            duplicatedEquipment.save()
            duplicatedEquipment.name = "${originalEquipment.name.replace("(copy)", "").trim()} (copy)"
            duplicatedEquipment.extras = duplicateExtras originalEquipment.extras, duplicatedEquipment
            duplicatedEquipments << duplicatedEquipment
        }

        duplicatedEquipments
    }

    /**
     * Performs a deep copy of a given locations extras.
     *
     * @param originalExtras The original location extras
     * @param duplicatedEquipment The duplicated equipment; needed for belongsTo association
     * @return The duplicated extras set.
     */
    Set<EquipmentQuestionExtra> duplicateExtras(Set<EquipmentQuestionExtra> originalExtras, Equipment duplicatedEquipment) {
        Set<EquipmentQuestionExtra> duplicatedExtras = []

        for (originalExtra in originalExtras) {
            EquipmentQuestionExtra duplicatedExtra = new EquipmentQuestionExtra()
            duplicatedExtra.properties = originalExtra.properties
            duplicatedExtra.equipment = duplicatedEquipment
            duplicatedExtra.uuid = UUIDGenerator.createUniqueId()
            duplicatedExtra.dateModified = DateUtil.currentDate
            duplicatedExtra.save()
            duplicatedExtras << duplicatedExtra
        }

        duplicatedExtras
    }

    /**
     * Performs a deep copy of a given locations products.
     *
     * @param originalLocation The original location
     * @param duplicatedLocation The duplicated location
     * @return The duplicated product set.
     */
    Set<RecommendedProduct> duplicateProducts(Location originalLocation, Location duplicatedLocation) {
        Set<RecommendedProduct> originalProducts = originalLocation.products
        Set<RecommendedProduct> duplicatedProducts = []

        for (originalProduct in originalProducts) {
            RecommendedProduct duplicatedProduct = new RecommendedProduct()
            duplicatedProduct.properties = originalProduct.properties
            duplicatedProduct.location = duplicatedLocation
            duplicatedProduct.uuid = UUIDGenerator.createUniqueId()
            duplicatedProduct.dateModified = DateUtil.currentDate
            duplicatedProduct.save()
            duplicatedProducts << duplicatedProduct
        }

        duplicatedProducts
    }
}
```

Comment: Working for me. Thx very much, I wasted about half a day on the problem.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a problem with your clone method: you clone "all" properties, including the ID, which is a bad idea with deep cloning. [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692871/found-shared-references-to-a-collection-org-hibernate-hibernateexception) explanes that your error is thrown when an object has the same properties than another in the hibernate cache, BUT with another reference.

So, you just have to set the `id` property of your objects to `null` (or exclude it from the properties copy) to force hibernate to detect that it's a new object. If it's still not working, call the [discard](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Domain%20Classes/discard.html) method on your object before the `save`.

Answer (score 0):

You are saving the children entities. Dont do that, only save the entity Survey (root). Others will be saved by cascade.

In other hand as @Joch says, using clone is not the right approach in this case.

You should create a duplicate method of you entity. Here is an example how to clone a this structure type. It is a test with n questions, and each question has n answers, with a "duplicate" method for each class.

```
class Test {

    String name

    static hasMany = [
            /**
             * Each question of the test
             */
            questions: Question
    ]

    /**
     * Duplicates this test
     */
    Test duplicate(){
         Test test = new Test(name:this.name)
         this.questions.each{ question ->
             test.addToQuestions(question.duplicate(test))
         }
         test
    }
}


class Question {

    Integer questionOrder
    String title

    /**
     * Each question belong to a Test
     */
    static belongsTo = [test:Test]

    static hasMany = [
            /**
             * Each answer of the test
             */
            answers: Answer
    ]

    /**
     * Duplicates this test to another edition
     * @param edition to be duplicated
     * @return duplicated question
     */
    Question duplicate(Test test){
        if(test){
            Question question = new Question(title:this.title)
            this.answers.each{ answer->
                question.addToAnswers(answer.duplicate())
            }
            test.addToQuestions(question)
            question
        }
    }
}

class Answer {

    String title
    boolean correct
    /**
     * Each answer belongs to a question
     */
    static belongsTo = [question:Question]

    /**
     * Duplicates this answer to another question
     * @param edition to be duplicated
     * @return duplicated question
     */
    Answer duplicate(){
        Answer answer = new Answer()
        answer.properties['title','correct'] = this.properties['title','answerOrder','correct']
        answer
    }
}
```

In Answer.duplicate() you have an example of how to bind certain properties from other object.

Comment: What's the purpose of checking for null with the  `if` block? It doesn't make sense to me since it's the only method with the signature `duplication(Domain)`. I've been playing around with your suggestions, however it's throwing null exceptions on the collections.

Comment: Sorry I cleaned a real code and I have forgotten to delete that line.

Comment: I have seen you are saving the children entities. Dont do that, only save the entity Survey. Others will be saved by cascade